# WKWebView Loading is Too Slow

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using MarkDonwView Library : https://github.com/keitaoouchi/MarkdownView

Which is converting MD String to show as a webview. Rendering is taking too long as it loads everything and then shows the view. Is it possible to make image loading async while showing text body ASAP so it will not look like its too slow ?

This is how it is loading the html file.

```
 if bundle.bundleIdentifier?.hasPrefix("org.cocoapods") == true {
      htmlURL = bundle.url(forResource: "index",
                           withExtension: "html",
                           subdirectory: "MarkdownView.bundle")
    } else {
      htmlURL = bundle.url(forResource: "index",
                           withExtension: "html")
    }

    if let url = htmlURL {
      let templateRequest = URLRequest.init(url: url, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 60) //URLRequest(url: url)

      let escapedMarkdown = self.escape(markdown: markdown) ?? ""
      let imageOption = enableImage ? "true" : "false"
      let script = "window.showMarkdown('\(escapedMarkdown)', \(imageOption));"
      let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

      let controller = WKUserContentController()
      controller.addUserScript(userScript)

      let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
      configuration.userContentController = controller

      let wv = WKWebView(frame: self.bounds, configuration: configuration)
      wv.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = self.isScrollEnabled
      wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      wv.navigationDelegate = self
      addSubview(wv)
      wv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
      wv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
      wv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
      wv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
      wv.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor

      self.webView = wv

      wv.load(templateRequest)
    } else {
      // TODO: raise error
    }
```

Comment: You can do it by load your stuff in background more and then if you want any UI related changes then make it in main thread.

Comment: Actually everything is done on a click. So it should show at least the html text and load image asynchronously. @iPatel